# How is this JavaScript pattern called and how do I use it in the right way?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have taken over an existing project which uses JavaScript in the following way. I would like to understand how/why this is done and get some more information on how to use it efficiently. Is there a name for this pattern so I can do some more research?

**index.html (before `</body>`)**

```
<script src="main.js"></script>
<script src="navigation.js"></script>
<script>
    var navigation = new window.Navigation();
    window.App.navigation = navigation;
    window.App.navigation.init(this);
</script>
```

**main.js (shortened...)**

```
App = {};
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log('doc ready');
});
```

**navigation.js (shortened...)**

```
window.Navigation = (function () {
return function () {
    return {
        scope: undefined,
        someElement:undefined,

        init: function (pScope) {
            this.scope = pScope;
            this.someElement = $(this.scope.querySelectorAll('.some-element'));
            this.someMethod();
        },
        someMethod: function() {
            // some jQuery
            if($(this).hasClass('some-class')) {
                self.anotherMethod();
            }
        },
        anotherMethod: function() {
            // some jQuery
            $(this.someElement).show();
            this.yetAnotherMethod();
        },
        yetAnotherMethod: function() {
            // some jQuery
            $(this.someElement).stop().animate({duration:200});
        }
    };
};
}());
```

Besides understanding what this pattern is and why one would use it, I have a practical question:

The navigation.js controller is responsible for our element `.navigation`. Right now, if there is more than one .navigation, interacting with one .navigation element causes all .navigation elements to react to interaction.

How can I fire the controller to controll each .navigation element for itself? (I hope my vocabulary is correct here)

It works if I call the controller (inside index.html) in the following way with jQuery, but it doesn't feel right:

```
$('.navigation').each(function() {
    var navigation = new window.Navigation();
    window.App.navigation = navigation;
    window.App.navigation.init(this);
});
```

Comment: `someMethod` looks like there's a bug by referencing `this`, also would recommend not using `window.` and instead just reference variables directly

Comment: Are you sure this is even working?  Insert some alerts or console logs into the script to see if the JS is being triggered.

Comment: Yes, it works. I have just simplified the code because the original stuff is way to long to post here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a JavaScript Object Literal or Singleton pattern.  Here's a really basic example:

```
<script>

var exampleObj = {

    settings : {
        'test' : 'example'
    },

    alertSettings : function(){
        alert(this.settings.test);
    },

    gotCha : function(){
        var self = this;
        $('body').animate({"background-color":"red"},2000,function(){
            alert(self.settings.test);
            self.alertSettings();
        });
    },

    init : function() {
        this.alertSettings();
        this.gotCha();
    }

}

exampleObj.init(); // triggers the events

</script>
```

Init triggers the `alertSettings()` method and then `gotCha()`.  You will notice that `gotCha()` redeclares `this` as `self`.  That's because there is a function within a function inside `gotCha()` and `this` is limited (or scoped) to the function it is contained within.  So the inner function refers to the `self` alias (or closure) because the variable it wants to alert is in the outer function `this`.

Quick and dirty.  I hope this helps.  *** Needs jQuery

Comment: Good answer.  To the other points, `$('.navigation').each(function()`  the each is unnecessary.  A class command will fire for all elements with said class automatically.  If you just want to call one, give it an id, or use traversing selectors like `:nth-child(n)` or `:first()` etc

Comment: If I wanted to attach events to individual elements I would user .bind() and then refer to the clicked element like so     `$('.classString').bind('click',function(e){ $(e.target).css('background-color':'red'); alert('woot'); });`

Comment: Let's say I have two elements .navigation ... I want them to behave the same. For example if I click on the .open button I want to slide the .navigation open or whatever. But of course if I want to open navigation A i do not want to open navigation B at the same time. But this is exactly what is happening right now - unless I use the jQuery approach.

Comment: Use `$('').bind()` to attach events to the elements.  See previous comment.