# How to trigger after functions with Owl Carousel 2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

I use a owl carousel and I want to detect the first and last elements when active. I'm trying to trigger a function with the afterAction attribute but I cannot make it happen.

This is the initialiser:

```
$('#carousel').owlCarousel({
        slideBy: 4,
        loop: true,
        margin: 10,
        responsiveClass: true,
        responsive: {
            0: {
                items: 1,
                nav: true
            },
            600: {
                items: 3,
                nav: false
            },
            1000: {
                items: 4,
                nav: true,
                loop: false
            }
        },
        afterAction : afterAction
    });

    function afterAction(){
        console.log("owl after action");
    }
```

Comment: have you tried adding `.done(function(){ whatevs; });` ?  `$('carouself').owlCarousel( .... settings ... ).done(function(){  afterAction(); });`

Comment: @b_dubb It throws me: "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).owlCarousel(...).done is not a function".

Comment: looks like you'll have to try another method.  see my answer below.  another possible solution would be to use a `promise` but I'm not sure that will work here either.  The singleton pattern approach below WILL.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the elements inside the carousel (I'm assuming you're referring to the panels) like this `$('#carousel .owl-item:first)` and `$('#carousel .owl-item:last)`.  To create the carousel and trigger a function only after the carousel is built try the method below.

```
var exampleApp = {

  createCarousel : function(options) {
    $('#carousel').owlCarousel({
        slideBy: 4,
        loop: true,
        margin: 10,
        responsiveClass: true,
        responsive: {
            0: {
                items: 1,
                nav: true
            },
            600: {
                items: 3,
                nav: false
            },
            1000: {
                items: 4,
                nav: true,
                loop: false
            }
        }
     });
     this.afterwards(options.passedStr);
  },

  afterWards : function( testStr ){ // passedStr becomes testStr here
    console.log('afterwards method ',testStr );
  },


  init : function (options) {
    this.createCarousel(options);
  }

}

exampleApp.init({"passedStr":"singleton pattern"});
```

This is a [JavaScript Singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25693368/how-is-this-javascript-pattern-called-and-how-do-i-use-it-in-the-right-way/25693596#25693596) pattern.

Answer (score 0):

For the first and last "elements" that are visible in the carousel:

In the afterAction function this.visibleItems returns an array of the visible items displayed in the carousel.  The first visible item will always be at array position 0 and the last will be the length - 1.

```
function afterAction() {
    var first = this.visibleItems[0];
    var last = this.visibleItems[this.visibleItems.length - 1];
    console.log(first, last);
    console.log($('.owl-item')[first], $('.owl-item')[last]);
}

$('#carousel').owlCarousel({
    slideBy: 4,
    loop: true,
    margin: 10,
    responsiveClass: true,
    responsive: {
        0: {
            items: 1,
            nav: true
        },
        600: {
            items: 3,
            nav: false
        },
        1000: {
            items: 4,
            nav: true,
            loop: false
        }
    },
    afterAction : afterAction
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please consider adding a bit more of an explanation with your answer.